# How to replace the new line when the previous doesn't end with point?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I'm trying to replace the newlines by single space when the previous line does not ends with point.

I mean, this input:

```
 hello.
stack.
  overflow
 friends.
  this
  is
   a.
 test.
```

Would output this:

```
 hello.
stack.
  overflow friends.
  this is a.
 test.
```

I tried something like:

```
sed 's/[^\.] *\\\n */ /g' input.txt
```

But seems that I can't match the newline trought sed in this case. And I don't know how could I exclude the point so it wouldn't be replaced as well.

**EDIT:**

With this input none of the solutions posted works.
I do `cat -vte` to let you know that there is not any weird charapter:

```
[jmrodriguez@zlpre1 ~]$ cat -vte /home/jmrodriguez/copytso.txt
       01  WE-ENTRADA.                                                          $
           03 WE-WILL-ROCK1           PIC X(6).                                      $
           03 WE-WILL-ROCK2           PIC X(3).                                      $
           03 WE-WILL-ROCK3            PIC X(7).                                      $
           03 WE-WILL-ROCK4     $
                             PIC S9(11)V99 COMP-3.                          $
           03 WE-WILL-ROCK5     PIC S9(11)V99 COMP-3.                          $
           03 MUST-WORKS     PIC S9(11)V99 COMP-3.                          $
           03 HELLO     PIC S9(11)V99 COMP-3.                          $
           03 ALL     PIC S9(11)V99 COMP-3.                          $
           03 YOU    PIC S9(11)V99 COMP-3.                          $
           03 FRIENDS    PIC S9(11)V99 COMP-3.                          $
           03 LOL    PIC S9(11)V99 COMP-3.                          $
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this `awk`:

```
awk 'p{sub(/^ */, "")} !/\. *$/{p=p $0 " "; next} {print p $0; p=""}' file
 hello.
stack.
  overflow friends.
  this is a.
 test.
```

Comment: It does not works in one case. See the edited question, please. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

You could simply do this in Perl through negative lookbehind.

```
perl -pe 's/(?<!\.)\n/ /g' file
```

OR

Try the below if you want to remove  following spaces after the matched newline characters.

```
$ perl -00pe 's/(?<!\.)\n\s*/ /g' file
 hello.
stack.
  overflow friends.
  this is a.
 test.
```

Comment: It returns me only a line with all the content of the file... what could be the issue here?

Answer (score 2):

Using sed:

```
sed ':l /[^.] *$/{N;s/ *\n */ /; bl}' input
```

*Output:*

```
 hello.
stack.
  overflow friends.
  this is a.
 test.
```

Comment: just the ` *` before the first `$` that is not exactly what is asked (but understand the purpose), maybe propose the 2 syntax

Comment: I would include a space in the character class: `[^. ]` instead of `[^.]`. Otherwise the pattern matches the string "`foo.   `".

Comment: can you also post the desired output, I think the output of this one is reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

This is also handy (if you can live with the extra dot):

```
$ awk '{gsub("\n|  *"," ");print $0RS}' RS='.'  infile                                   
 hello.
 stack.
  overflow  friends.
  this  is  a.
  test.
 .
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n ':load
$ !{N;b load
   }
s/\([^.]\)\(\n\)/\1/g
p' YourFile
```

Preload the file first, than change all non dot ended line at once

Answer (score 0):

Using xargs and awk

```
xargs | awk 'BEGIN{FS=".";OFS=".\n"}{$1=$1;print $0}'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;N;s/\([^.]\)\n/\1 /;ta;P;D' file
```

Keep a rolling window of 2 lines and check junction of them for a non-period.